# Remove pixel patch in image which is stored as array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have an array `I` which stores `N` images of size `P` (number of pixels). Every image is of size `P = q*q`.

Now I want to delete patches of size `ps` around a selected index `IDX` (set all values to zero).

My approach was to reshape every single image using `reshape(q,q)` and delete the pixels around `IDX`. I also have to check if the index is not outside the image.

Here is an example:

BEFORE: [image]

AFTER: [image]

My code is a real bottleneck and I would like to know if there is a way to improve the performance of my approach.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 

def myplot(I):
    imgs = 5
    for i in range(imgs**2):
        plt.subplot(imgs,imgs,(i+1))
        plt.imshow(I[i].reshape(q,q), cmap="viridis", interpolation="none")
        plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

N = 10000
q = 28
P = q*q
I = np.ones((N,P))
myplot(I)

ps = 5
IDX = np.random.randint(0,P,(N,1))
x0, y0 = np.unravel_index(IDX,(q,q))

t0 = time.time()

# HOW TO IMPROVE THIS PART ? #
for i in range(N):
    img = I[i].reshape(q,q)
    for x in range(ps):
        for y in range(ps):
            if (x0[i]+x < q) and (y0[i]+y < q):
                img[x0[i]+x,y0[i]+y] = 0.0
    I[i] = img.reshape(1,q*q)

print(time.time()-t0)
myplot(I)
```

I call this code (without the plotting procedure) about one million times from another code. Every call takes about 1 second on my system. This makes the code so far quite useless.

Any advice?

Comment: Hi! I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. On my computer it takes 1.745 seconds to run the code in the post.
2. There's no need for the array of random indexes to be two-dimensional:

   ```
   IDX = np.random.randint(0,P,(N,1))
   ```

   In fact this is harmful for performance, because it means that `x0[i]` is an array of length 1 (not a scalar) and so `img[x0[i]+x,y0[i]+y]` requires "fancy indexing" which is slower than normal indexing.

   It would be simpler to make the array of indexes one-dimensional:

   ```
   IDX = np.random.randint(P, size=N)
   ```

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.459 seconds (26.3% of the original).
3. There is no need to reassign `I[i]` at the end of the loop. When you call the [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method on a NumPy array, what you get is a *view* onto the original array (not a copy) if possible. (And it is possible in this case.) So updating the view also updates the original.

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.449 seconds (25.8%).
4. Instead of looping over `range(N)` and then looking up `I[i]` and `x0[i]` and `y0[i]`, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to loop over all the arrays simultaneously:

   ```
   for img, xx, yy in zip(I, x0, y0):
       img = img.reshape(q,q)
       for x in range(ps):
           for y in range(ps):
               if xx + x < q and yy + y < q:
                   img[xy + x, yy + y] = 0.0
   ```

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.358 seconds (20.5%).
5. Instead of looping over all the pixels in the patch and updating each pixel individually, use slices to update the whole region in one step:

   ```
   for image, x, y in zip(I, x0, y0):
       image.reshape(q, q)[x:x + ps, y:y + ps] = 0.0
   ```

   This works because NumPy (and Python generally) ensures that the bounds of a slice do not go beyond the end of the array. See the [slicing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

   > The slice of \$s\$ from \$i\$ to \$j\$ is defined as the sequence of items with index \$k\$ such that \$i \le k < j\$. If \$i\$ or \$j\$ is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`.

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.025 seconds (1.4%).
6. We can vectorize the additions `x + ps` and `y + ps`:

   ```
   for image, x, y, x1, y1 in zip(I, x0, y0, x0 + ps, y0 + ps):
       image.reshape(q, q)[x:x1, y:y1] = 0.0
   ```

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.021 seconds (1.2%).
7. We could avoid the reshape inside the loop by doing a single reshape of the whole `I` array:

   ```
   images = I.reshape(N, q, q)
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   for image, x, y, x1, y1 in zip(images, x0, y0, x0 + ps, y0 + ps):
       image[x:x1, y:y1] = 0.0
   ```

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.018 seconds (1.0%).
8. We can halve the number of indexing operations by indexing the `images` array just once on each loop iteration:

   ```
   for i, x, y, x1, y1 in zip(range(N), x0, y0, x0 + ps, y0 + ps):
       images[i, x:x1, y:y1] = 0.0
   ```

   This reduces the runtime to about 0.011 seconds (0.6%).

That's about 150 times speedup overall, so calling this a million times will still take about 3 hours on my computer. There may be other improvements to be had if only we could see more of your code, but you'll need to make a new post for that.

Comment: Awesome! Now I try to understand everything.

Comment: I am still amazed by your answer. Did not think that it would go so fast using Python. There is one thing I noted using your approach. Given a odd patch size, for example `ps=3` and coordinates `x0` and `y0` your approach deletes 9 pixels from top left to bottom right (that is the square from [x0,y0] to [x0+ps,y0+ps]). But how can I delete the surrounding pixels instead, that is [x0-1, y0-1] to [x0+1, y0+1]? I tried just doing `x0=x0-1` and `y0=y0-1`which results quite often in images where no pixels got deleted. What would be the right approach to do that?

Comment: Use `np.maximum(x0 - 1, 0)` instead of `x0 - 1`.

Comment: I wanted to replace the patches with random numbers instead of zeros. So I tried `images[i, x:x1, y:y1] = np.random.rand(x1-x,y1-y)` which does not work. Any suggestions?